# How can I speed up the image loading or enhance perceived performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a site where a user can scroll through a series of frames of a particular anime scene. So each frame is a single image. Atmost **500** images can make up the scene.
That means I download atmost **500** images prior to showcasing a particular scene and in-place show a custom **loader**.

**Things I have done to reduce the download time :-**

- Used s3 bucket with CDN Edge servers (from DigitalOcean) to get the assets faster.
- Used an Image Optimisation service by ImageKit to help me with **Image Transformation** on the fly. So I have few metrics on the basis of which, I dynamically request for the **image of certain width and height**. My front-end app connects to this service which internally gets stuff from the s3 bucket.
- The same service provided me with a service-worker which factors in network speed and can reduce the quality of images being requested for slow network conditions. (This sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. Needs a better implementation by me I think)
- Stuff like `link rel="preconnect"` in `index.html` to reduce **DNS resolution** time and subsequent TLS negotiation and handshake time for the **Imagekit** service url (This seems mostly like a initial load optimisation but correct me if I am wrong)

**My implementation :-**

- I am not using standard `img src='...'` way of loading all those images.
- I am using `fetch` to get the image content  and create a `blob` url and on formation of atmost **500** blob urls, I pass them one by one to a **image** created using `new Image()` and set the `src` to the `blob` url.
- All those images are stored in a single **React ref** and by looping over that `ref` array, I draw the **images** one by one on a `canvas`. Chose a **React ref** because it could very well handle that much memory content and help me achieve smooth scroll on the images.

**Bottleneck** - Most browsers can really just fetch **6** assets from the same domain in parallel. That means for an awesome network connection too , loading of my single anime scene can take **5-10s**, for a little less ones **10-30**s and so on. I am still okay with the **5-10s** mark but more than that will get too much for the end user. Also I didn't chose to load a certain images at once and certain later because it's totally possible for the user to scroll so fast that the later images haven't loaded by that time giving a **discontinuous experience**.

What **performance optimisation** options I have for this app ?

Here is the live site - https://animeccha.com/home

Here is the source code - https://github.com/lapstjup/animeccha

**Note** - Subsequent requests for the same scene are fast since they get fetched from **disk-cache**. The **ImageKit** service responds with **Cache-control : certain max-age** and I think that's why **disk-cache** works. Correct me I am wrong but I think the browser will free up **disk** space time to time so those **cached** images might not remain **cached** for long. So it's really that initial **non-cached** loading I want to speed up.